# symfony2 : Get form errors in controller

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I validated my form through **AJAX CALL** but can't retrieve "error messages".

Here is what i put :

```
$newRdvForm = $this->createForm(new RdvType());

$newRdvForm->handleRequest($request);

if ($newRdvForm->isValid()) { 
   // set of instructions to be performed when the form is valid
}
else {

   $errors= array();

   foreach ($newRdvForm->getErrors() as $key => $error) {
        $errors[$key] = $error->getMessage();
   }   

   $response = new Response(json_encode($errors));
   $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

   return $response; 

}
```

I used symfony 2.7. The above code doesn't retrieve  the error messages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe Your for myte is builded from multiple nested types? Try to use getErrors(true)

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form/introduction.html#accessing-form-errors

Comment: i used  $resolver->setDefaults(array('allow_extra_fields' => true )); when i buid the form

Comment: Now i can retrieve all error messages but how can i retrieve the "**INPUT ID**"  or the "**INPUT NAME**" ??

Answer (score 2):

```
/**
 * get Error Messages From Form.
 * @param \Symfony\Component\Form\Form $form
 * @return array
 */
protected function getErrorMessages(\Symfony\Component\Form\Form $form) {
  $errors = array();
 if ($form->count() > 0) {
    foreach ($form->all() as $child) {
        if (!$child->isValid()) {
           $errors[$child->getName()] = (String) $form[$child->getName()]->getErrors();
        }
     }
 }
 return $errors;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**for the list of errors in the form you can leave it in an array**

```
   foreach ($form->getErrors(true, false) as $error) {
                $errors[] = $error->current()->getMessage();
            }
```